# What is the default home folder and bookmarks structure?

Tags: pantheon-files, home

I accidentally messed up with the structure of my home folder and the bookmarks in the sidebar. Can someone please provide me with a screenshot how the default home folder structure and default folder bookmarks in the "Files" file manager look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of Files after a fresh installation:

[image]

FYI, you could have seen it yourself by logging into a guest session :)

Comment: Finally found a use case for the guest session. Thanks for sharing! :)